# Inequality of absolute value of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

If $ z $ is a complex number, does it follow that $ |z| \ge z $ like with real numbers? The way I justify it is by saying that if $ z \in \mathbb{C}, $ then $ z = a +bi $ for some $ a,b \in \mathbb{R}. $ 
If $ b = 0, $ we get back to the case when $ z $ is a real number.
If $ b \neq 0, $ then $ |z| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} > \sqrt{a^2} = |a| \ge a, $ meaning $ |z| > Re(z), $ so $ |z| > z. $
Can anyone suggest if this theorem is true?

Comment: The problem is that for complex numbers $|z| \ge z$ doesn't make sense.  There is no order on complex numbers that extends the usual order on real numbers in a way that respects addition and multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial thinking is a common mistake. $z$ is a complex number, and so has value, in some sense, "in two directions" in the complex plane. The idea of '$>$' or '$<$' has no meaning for complex numbers for this reason (in an intuitive sense). Even when the imaginary part is zero, it is a dangerous game to state things like $|z|\geq z$ in proofs where complex numbers are the main context.

If you are interested in more formal ideas about why statements like yours are 'meaningless', it may behoove you to read up on equivalence relations.